# Tensorflow: Do created TFRecords files always have a larger file size than the original data?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have an folder of jpg images 5gb in size in total, and I convert my files into TFRecords, splitting it into 280 for training, 120 for validation, and 100 for test, is the total file size of the 3 created TFrecords files always larger than 5Gb?

Because currently I am having a tfrecords file of ~100mb for the training file, and around 40-50mb for the validation and test files. I suspect the files may be created wrongly but I have no way of verifying it. Thus, if a combined file size of the 3 tfrecords files is lesser than 5gb, does this mean the files are created wrong?

How can I check further whether the files have read the correct data? (could I read the data from a tfrecords file? So far, the shapes for the tensor data are correct.)

Comment: It does not a priori mean that. TFRecord is a binary format, so, e.g. if you had a large text document (encoded in ascii), encoding it in TFRecord could decrease the size a little. But, in your case, as jpeg is a compression format it seems mathematically impossible to compress the data more than 10x, so my guess is that something, somewhere, went terribly wrong :)

Comment: I'm using the code from https://github.com/mnuke/tf-slim-mnist/blob/master/convert_to_records.py and I assumed that as long as I fed in a 4D tensor, the files should be converted automatically. Could this be wrong?

Comment: Well, I don't know what is wrong. My comment was made entirely based on my mathematical intuition -- as jpeg is a compressed format, it is information-dense, so it is impossible to compress it much more without loss of information. You can observe it trying to compress the same folder with `tar` or `zip` -- it will result in a >4GB file (I guess). What may be the case, though, is that the TFRecord file doesn't really contain the pictures, but only some pointers to them -- then it would make sense that the file is much smaller.

Comment: Can you try to do two tests?
1. compress the folder with `tar` and observe the size -- it is basically a lower bound on the size of the file containing all the information from the folder
2. try to read the data from the TFRecords after moving the data away from the folder or renaming it -- it will confirm or disprove my hypothesis that TFRecord only contain pointers to data on disk.

Comment: If it's much less than 5GB, then the tfrecords are almost certainly wrong. You can write a tensorflow program using `tf.tf_record_iterator` to check out what's in. Perhaps you only stored the filenames instead of the data?

Comment: @sygi My compressed file size is 4GB, which is far higher than my tfrecords files. I suspect they are converted wrongly. 

to drpng: I used tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator but I only received a tf object at the end. How can I read the files using this? I am currently using the traditional method of:


`reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features  = {serialized_example, ...}`


But I can't get any useful information out. Printing the individual features like image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw], tf.uint8) gives just a tensor object.

Comment: I have managed to use the code from here: https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/2BsB4H97vM0 to read using the tf_record_iterator function. However, the reading prints nothing although I've explicitly stated for it to print. The code i used to read can be found here: http://paste.ofcode.org/HnJrkXrmb2M3LT4AEDA9Rq

Comment: @leekwotsin I'm running into the situation -- 7x's the size of images. Is this normal behavior?